# ImageField with django-storages leads to: "Error parsing the X-Amz-Credential parameter; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-west-1'"

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to add an `ImageField` to a model called `LucyGuide` which will save user-uploaded images to S3 using [`django-storages`](http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html). Here is the (simplified) model:

```
class LucyGuide(TimeStampedModel):
    headshot = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

I've added the following to my `settings.py`:

```
# Use Boto3 backend to interact with Amazon's S3
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

# Amazon S3 credentials (for django-storages)
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', default='')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', default='')

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME', default='')
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_S3_REGION_NAME')
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
# Use v4 of the signing protocol (recommended for all new projects)
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
```

where the actual keys are read from a `.env` file (using a mechanism similar to `django-decouple`).

To try this out, I uploaded a random picture for a `LucyGuide` in Django's admin UI:

[image]

In the shell, I'm able to access the `url` attribute of the guide's `headshot` field, which is indeed a link to an AWS bucket:

```
In [6]: guide = LucyGuide.objects.filter(bio__startswith="Kristen").first()

In [7]: guide
Out[7]: <LucyGuide: Kristen Hoover>

In [8]: guide.headshot
Out[8]: <ImageFieldFile: uploads/320px-Waaah.jpg>

In [9]: guide.headshot.url
Out[9]: 'https://lucy-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/320px-Waaah.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIMC2A%2F20180327%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180327T200248Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=ae75dbdd75d13020113c12ef2d655e3'
```

(where I've deleted parts of the URL). The problem is that when I try to go to this URL in the browser, I get a "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it" error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code>
<Message>
Error parsing the X-Amz-Credential parameter; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-west-1'
</Message>
<Region>us-west-1</Region>
<RequestId>1E053D94011E400F</RequestId>
<HostId>
jbkRHVj2y6ygppTsAo2+uOXgby0ok0mbsFsRogKqbu9jPMb+9eGe24nJv441vip3WpmwpFqlsYg=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

[image]

I've already tried to solve this by adding the `AWS_S3_REGION_NAME` setting (cf. http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html). The region `us-west-1` indicated by the error message seems to be the correct one, since the bucket is set up in "US West (N. California)":

[image]

All in all, I don't see why this error is occurring despite setting the correct `AWS_S3_REGION_NAME`. How can I fix this error?

**Update**

If I inspect the object in the bucket, I see that it has a "Link" which is much simpler than the one generated by the `url` property of the `headshot` field:

[image]

I'm thinking of just hard-coding the 'base URL' shown here into the API endpoint I'm trying to build that retrieves image URLs, but this doesn't seem like an elegant solution. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reading (and setting a breakpoint in) the `django-storages` source code, I was able to solve the problem by adding the setting

```
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

which changes it from its default value of `True`. Now the `url` attribute generates a URL without an authentication querystring:

```
In [2]: guide = LucyGuide.objects.filter(bio__startswith='Darrell').first()

In [3]: guide.headshot
Out[3]: <ImageFieldFile: uploads/Waaah.jpg>

In [4]: guide.headshot.url
Out[4]: 'https://lucy-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/Waaah.jpg'
```

Comment: I maybe wrong here, but your opening a hole on the bucket. The querystring auth is there for good reason, it restricts the access to the image for a specific period of time. Without this, anyone with public read ability would be able to see and download all other images from your uploads folder as well. If its intended its fine, but not sure it is.

Comment: This seems to have worked for me. I got 403 Not Authorized when making GET requests to public-visible artifacts on DigitalOcean Spaces. It seems to have been related to all of the query string auth parameters generated by storages, which were somehow causing DO Spaces to throw the error. I got no error when requesting the same resources via the URL without the query string parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of turning off querystring you can simply use `AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-2'    # replace us-east-2 with your region`. It's much safer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the variable AWS_S3_REGION_NAME to settings.py.
It could be missing in your env file
See also: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

Comment: This worked for me, rather than doign without query like accepted answer

Comment: I passed this value into `boto3.client` constructor with the parameter `region_name`. I had a need for services to use different region names so a global django setting was not sufficient.